# Printing ListArrays to a txt file

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method that is suppose to take 3 arrays and save them to a txt file.  But it doesnt print to the list. Here is my code for the method

```
public static void saveAndExit(int count, String[] makeArray, String[] moduleArray, double [] msrpArray) throws IOException{
  File carList = new File("cars_list.txt");
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(carList);
  int index = 0;
  String[] finalMSRPArray = new String[12];
  for (int i = 0; i < msrpArray.length; i++){
      finalMSRPArray[i] = String.valueOf(msrpArray[i]);
  }
    while(count < makeArray.length && count < moduleArray.length && count < msrpArray.length){
        pw.write(makeArray[index]+"\n");
        pw.write(moduleArray[index]+"\n");
        pw.write(finalMSRPArray[index]+"\n");
        index++;
    }

    pw.close();
```

}

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is it doing, and what is it *supposed* to do? Also, what is `count`, and are the arrays supposed to have all the same lengths or different lengths?

Comment: The entire program is suppose to ask the user to input a make, module, and the msrp price. So in a different method the user can add to the list. and after adding a car to the list, the program will prompt the user to add, modify, remove, or save the list. and if they click on save the list. it is suppose to over write anything that was on the list previously with what they added it. if that make sense

Comment: Your for loop loops through the msrpArray but it dont see where you add values to this array.

Comment: count is suppose to how many "cars" are in the list.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not in the vehicle industry, and I can't fill in the gaps in the information you provide. So please edit your question, and add the actual requirements of the assignment, and since you are talking about a list, how you implemented the list. If we don't know the problem domain, we can't tell you why your implementation is not working, though I can see a potential endless loop here.